# How to build a flexible HTML form layout?

Tags: html, css, layout, forms, css-frameworks

I want to build a flexible html form with the following features:

1. Label should stay right above his component (see image below);
2. Components should fill (width dimension) all the space available on the screen, with a minimum width configuration;
3. If the screen width doesn't fit all form components, they should be stacked;

[image: HTML Form with components filling all screen width]
**HTML Form with components filling all screen width**

[image: Same HTML Form with reduced screen width]
**Same HTML Form with reduced screen width**

What is the more elegant solution to achieve this result, without using html table and only HTML + CSS?

Comment: You'll want to use CSS media queries - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
 
  <title></title>
  
</head>
<body>
  <form class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
    <label>field 1</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="text1">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
    <label>field 2</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="text2">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
    <label>field 3</label>
    <select class="form-control">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
</select>
  </div>
</div>
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-8">
    <label>field 4</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="text3">
    </div>
   <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-8">
    <label>field 6</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="text4">
  </div> 
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12"
    <label>field5</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
  </div>
  </div>
<br>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">OK</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info">CANCEL</button>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is all what you want, done by using the best way, use bootstrap,you will need to practice bootstrap, for reference here u can go [Bootstrap forms](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms). Happy coding!

Comment: Accepted because of the code concision and because it takes advantage of a very well established framework, no to mention it refrains from reinventing the wheel. Thank you @Manish .

Comment: Welcome, Happy Coding! @Davi

Answer (score 1):

This should do it :

```css
.form-group {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}

.form-control {
    padding: 3px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
}

.form-control input,
.form-control select,
.form-control textarea {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
}

.form-control textarea {
    resize: vertical;
}

#form-group-1 .form-control {
    width: 33.333%;
}

#form-group-2 .form-control {
    width: 50%;
}

#form-group-3 .form-control {
    width: 100%;
}

#form-group-4 .form-control {
    width: 6em;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
    #form-group-1 .form-control {
        width: 50%;
    }
    
    #form-group-2 .form-control {
        width: 66.6666%;
    }
}
```

```html
<form>
    <div class="form-group" id="form-group-1">
        <div class="form-control">
            <label for="field1">Field 1</label>
            <input name="field1" id="field1" placeholder="text1">
        </div>
        <div class="form-control">
            <label for="field2">Field 2</label>
            <input name="field2" id="field2" placeholder="text2">
        </div>
        <div class="form-control">
            <label for="field3">Field 3</label>
            <select name="field3" id="field3">
               <option value="1">Option 1</option>
               <option value="2">Option 2</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" id="form-group-2">
        <div class="form-control">
            <label for="field4">Field 4</label>
            <input name="field4" id="field4" placeholder="text4">
        </div>
        <div class="form-control">
            <label for="field5">Field 5</label>
            <input name="field5" id="field5" placeholder="text5">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" id="form-group-3">
        <div class="form-control">
            <label for="field6">Field 6</label>
            <textarea name="field6" id="field6"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" id="form-group-4">
        <div class="form-control">
            <input type="submit" value="OK" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-control">
            <input type="button" value="CANCEL" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

(see also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/yfnrv8fe/5/))

Comment: Thumbs up because this solution doens't need any external dependency. Thank you @john-slegers .